# What is the difference between "for each in list" and "for each in list[0:]"

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This is my code chunk. "valid" is a list of numeric values, and this snippet is supposed to remove the element under test if the regular expression does find a match. Trouble is, I'm getting different results based on whether I run "For each in valid" and "for each in valid[0:]". I don't understand why those two would behave different.

```
regexDupes = re.compile(r'(.)\1+')
for each in valid[0:]: ####<<<<<<<PROBLEM IS HERE
    qtyTest = regexDupes.findall(str(each))
    if len(qtyTest) == 0:
        valid.remove(each)
        print(each)
        invalid.append(each)

print(len(valid), len(invalid))

print(valid[0:25])
```

Comment: `list[0:]` is a *shallow copy* of the list, so your results are different because then you're not changing the length of what you're iterating over.

Comment: This would be clearer rewritten as a list-comprehension. For what purpose do you need to keep `invalid`? You could replace the lines inside the for-loop with a function `f(each)` that returns a tuple `(valid_entry, invalid_entry)`.  Then just call it with `valid, invalid = zip( f(each) for each in valid )`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `valid` is a `list` then `valid[:]` (or `valid[0:]` is a copy of that list.

It is required to iterate over a **copy** of a list when you mutate it during the loop. For instance when you add or remove elements.

If you don’t use a copy, the iterator can be lost and miss some elements.

If you want to make a discrimination you can write:

```
invalid = list(filter(lambda i: not regexDupes.findall(str(i)), valid))
valid = list(filter(lambda i: regexDupes.findall(str(i)), valid))
```

Comment: @Daniel, in most cases, it is (*short* lists) because short code is maintainable. Of course, you can use a loop with 2 variables, a `collections.Counter`, or other tricks, but it doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You must not iterate over lists, that you want to modify. So you have to make a copy of the list, or better, don't modify lists, but generate new ones:

```
regexDupes = re.compile(r'(.)\1+')
modified_valid = []
for each in valid:
    qtyTest = regexDupes.findall(str(each))
    if len(qtyTest) == 0:
        print(each)
        invalid.append(each)
    else:
        modified_valid.append(each)

print(len(modified_valid), len(invalid))

print(modified_valid[0:25])
```